# How can I make the whole line touchable area in SwiftUI List?

Tags: list, swiftui, row

This code only works when you touch the text. How can I make the whole line touchable area?

```
List(viewModel.countries) ) { country in
        Text(country.name)
            .padding(.vertical, 12)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.countryName = country.name
                self.countryId = country.countryId
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
    Text(country.name)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())         
        .onTapGesture {
```

Comment: Just add `Button` to your list, it will be automatically tapeable all cell area, with nicely tap effect...instead using frame